Bazel using a custom linker script and specs file in a cc_library
In my Bazel build system, I'm trying to use a custom linker script and custom specs file in the linkopts of a cc_library.
I'm having trouble getting it to work as Bazel rules.
The only way I can get it building is if I use absolute file paths.
How can I do this the proper Bazel way?
Thanks in advance.
My BUILD files (abridged):
filegroup(
    name = "spec_file",
    srcs = ["custom.spec"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
exports_files(["custom.spec"])

filegroup(
    name = "linker_file",
    srcs = ["lscript.ld"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
exports_files(["lscript.ld"])

cc_library(
    name = "some_lib",
    srcs = [":lib_files"],
    hdrs = [":include_files"],
    data = [":spec_file", ":linker_file"],
    linkopts = [
        "-Wl,-T,$(location :linker_file)", # DOES NOT WORK
        "-specs=$(location :spec_file)", # DOES NOT WORK
        #"-Wl,-T,/absolute/path/to/lscript.ld", # THIS WORKS
        #"-specs=/absolute/path/to/custom.spec", # THIS WORKS
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

...
cc_binary(
    name = "some_bin",
    deps = [
        "@some_repo//:some_lib",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    ...
    linkstatic = True,
)

When trying to build the cc_binary, linking fails:
$ bazel build //some_dir:some_bin
...
ERROR: /path/to/my/root/some_dir/BUILD:24:10: Linking some_dir/some_bin failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /dev/shm/bazel-sandbox.1a24f5537c6170d5a032c0965b98eee551e24447f59a396c5c7f00404e1cb681/linux-sandbox/23/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
...
  build/some_toolchain/gcc ... T,external/some_repo/lscript.ld '-specs=external/some_repo/Xilinx.spec')
...
gcc.real: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'external/some_repo/custom.spec': No such file or directory
...
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

However, if I go into the Bazel cache directory, I do see the referenced files and the same the command goes succeeds . e.g.
$ cd /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/7840cb557f96b5713c58c1924e221a09/execroot/__main__
$ ls external/some_repo/lscript.ld external/some_repo/Xilinx.spec
external/some_repo/lscript.ld external/some_repo/Xilinx.spec
$
$ build/some_toolchain/gcc ... T,external/some_repo/lscript.ld '-specs=external/some_repo/Xilinx.spec'
$ echo $?
0


The docs for the data field in cc_library says: "The list of files needed by this library at runtime." Important part here is "runtime", you need something available at build time. See https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library.
Instead, take a look at the documentation for linkopts:

Each element of this list that does not start with $ or - is assumed
to be the label of a target in deps. The list of files generated by
that target is appended to the linker options. An error is reported if
the label is invalid, or is not declared in deps.

What you definitely don't have here is that you included the linker files in deps. I'd try that first.
Concerning this documentation snippet, I believe it is outdated: When make variable substitution takes place, any referenced files (like yours) also need to be in deps. If the solution above, which is untested by me, turns out to be correct, please file a bug ticket so that the docs are improved!

I had tried moving deps around including data and file groups. What I ended up doing was make a custom_cc_binary Bazel rule that inherited the data et al. from whatever it depends on.
